# Attached iOS 11-style UISearchBar background image

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uisearchbar, ios11

I'd like to migrate my `tableHeaderView` based search bar to the new seamless search bar approach in iOS 11 by configuring `navigationItem.searchController`.

Since my navigation bar uses a custom background image, I'm wondering how to apply the same background image to the search bar as well. I tried

```
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarPromptBackground"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefaultPrompt];
[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarBackground"] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

to no avail. The search bar keeps the standard navigation bar background (with a `barTintColor` applied) but doesn't show the custom background image.

Comment: Use the appearance proxy?

Comment: The appearance proxy only automates setting the normal property and doesn't work if the normal property doesn't.

Comment: This iOS 11 change is a nightmare really...
Even the view hierarchy debuger is showing correctly the background image but the actual output doesn't display it... 
Setting the searchController is one thing, but if the customization is not possible, this new feature is not useful :(

Answer (score 3):

In my case I have a UISearchBar in a view, not placed in a UINavigationItem. A transparent background image I was setting wasn't showing up in iOS 11. However if I add a height constraint that forces the searchBar to be smaller the background image gets used for some reason. This is really odd behavior that must be a bug but it is working for me now.

If I do the following the background image gets used:

```
[[searchBar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44.0] setActive:YES];
```

Comment: With the fixed height you don't get the animated reveal appearance, right?

Comment: The constraint doesn't seem to affect reveal animation. But the backgroundImage isn't being used when it is put inside a navigationBar either. Mine isn't used that way so I hadn't tested yet it when I posted. Sorry, thought it was worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

I do a very similar thing in my application and discovered on IOS11 it's now broken. This is the code I had which sets my image across the Search and Scope bars, works fine up to IOS10:

```
[searchBarSearch setBackgroundImage:image];
[searchBarSearch setScopeBarBackgroundImage:image];
```

I fixed it by adding this to the .plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

Now my bar is coloured and changes as I select different options as it did before IOS11.

Hope this helps you!

Plasma

Comment: Thanks, good to know, but alas, going back to the legacy status bar appearance handling is not an option for me.

Comment: I couldn't see that API `setBackgroundImage` either. There is only the one with multiple parameters bar metrics etc. Which is broken on iOS 11.

Comment: I'm still using this code in IOS 11 and its still doing what I expect it to do, maybe you could expand on whats not working for you. My searchBarSearch object is a UISearchBar and I have the setBackgroundImage option with only one parameter (I also have the one with 3 parameters) in Xcode 9 and iOS 11.